# SSIS: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I have a variable in my SSIS package set to the following:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\CurrentUser\Dropbox\Eval\SynchDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Then I have an OLE DB Connection in my connection manager and I set the Connection string property of that connection to my variable.

I also created a data flow task with an OLE DB Source that is set to that connection, then I selected the table I needed, from the dropdown. But when I click on "Columns", I get an error:

```
 "The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager"
```

Which does not make sense since my connection string is valid. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: I would go back and check that you are actually setting the connection string to the right variable.

Comment: I just did - everything is correct. I only have two variables and both are connection strings

Comment: Is your variable being set dynamically from a configuration? Maybe teh configuration is incorrect.

Comment: nope, I set it by right-clicking on the control flow, selecting Variables, then changing the value of the variable

Comment: Maybe screenshots would help us see what is wrong